# Plugin sending emails to external addresses, not internal

Tags: plugins, email

I've set up a website on companyname.co.uk. I understand often a website may not be set up correctly to send emails, however Contact Form 7 is successfully sending emails to info@companyname.co.uk.

My issue is with the [Simple Job Board](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-job-board/) plugin, which successfully sends emails to any Gmail, Hotmail or even my agency email address. However it doesn't send to any @companyname.co.uk. There is no error message. The job is successfully applied for and the applicant gets an email confirming their application, but the company don't get a notification alerting them to the new application.

Confused as to why this would be the case when Contact Form 7 sends without an issue.

Comment: This may be blocked by the Spam filter. Need to verify with your hosting to see if it is in the guaranty or not. Do you use SMTP authentication to send the emails?

Comment: @drupalizeme Yeah we do. Is it still possible that it's getting blocked by the Spam filter if it's sending successfully on Contact Form 7? I'd have thought it would be blocked on both.

Comment: This is a little difficult to tell from this. But you could check the logs from the server to verified and be sure. If you use CPANEL or PLESK/ODIN it should have an area to mark mail delivery status.